# Using On-device Dictation/SODA in a self-built ChromiumOS/ChromeOS installation

Tags: google-chrome-os, soda, dictation

I have an instance of ChromiumOS (R114) that I built myself and I was trying to get the on-device dictation to work and I attempted the following:

1. Turned on on-device dictation in the [ash features](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ash/constants/ash_features.cc;l=1929?q=ash_features) and made sure that the ENABLE_SPEECH_SERVICE build flag was set to true.
2. In the ChromeOS instance I click on the dictation button on the bottom right hand side.
3. As a result of step 2 the [soda installer implementation code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/tags/114.0.5735.347/components/soda/soda_installer.cc#81) is executed and it tries to [install soda](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/tags/114.0.5735.347/components/soda/soda_installer.cc#98) and the language pack.
4. However the system fails to download the SODA DLC and I get an error relying that.

In the system logs I see the following:

```
WARNING chrome[966:966]: [dlcservice_client.cc(131)] DLC install is getting queued for: libsoda-model-en-us
ERROR dlcservice: [dlc_manager.cc(106)] GetDlc(...): Domain=dbus, Code=org.chromium.DlcServiceInterface.INVALID_DLC, Message=Passed unsupported DLC=libsoda
ERROR dlcservice: [dlc_service.cc(128)] Failed to install DLC=libsoda
ERROR dlcservice: [dlc_service.cc(107)] [CoreServicesAlert<install>] Failed to install DLC=libsoda
```

When the [dlc_manager](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform2/+/refs/heads/release-R114-15437.B/dlcservice/dlc_service.cc#127) executes the install function it fails at the [GetDlc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform2/+/refs/heads/release-R114-15437.B/dlcservice/dlc_manager.cc#176) function because there is no manifest for Soda in "/opt/google/dlc/". The [initialize code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform2/+/refs/heads/release-R114-15437.B/dlcservice/dlc_manager.cc#47) does not add it to the list of valid DLCs. I get that the DLC itself is closed source but is it not possible to download just the binary to use it for on-device dictation ?